# Testing Laravel Passport

Tags: php, laravel, testing, laravel-passport

I have a problem - I am using Laravel Passport for my api. I need to write tests. Whenever I use the `WithoutMiddleware` trait in my tests it disables the `Implicit route model binding` feature, which I use. Whenever I don't use that trait, I need to authenticate directly from my test. To do that, I need to create an API token via Passport.

Passport, however, needs to be installed before testing via `artisan passport:install`, because my tests are using `DatabaseTransactions` and `DatabaseMigrations` traits. When I do this, tests take enormous amount of time to run and I feel like it is not the right way to go about it. Isn't there a way to disable only the `auth` middleware? Or any other ideas to go about this?

Answer (score 2):

A little late to the party, but according to this [issue](https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/11691) this functionality is not currently supported with no plans to change that anytime soon.

However, all Laravel test classes inherit the `withoutMiddleware` method, which you can use to [disable middleware on specific methods](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/application-testing#disabling-middleware). Not sure if this is helpful to you, but just throwing it out there:

```
public function testBasicExample()
{
    $this->withoutMiddleware();

    $this->visit('/')
         ->see('Laravel 5');
}
```

You can also check to see if tests are running within the middleware itself by calling the `runningUnitTests()` method on the Application instance.

Answer (score 0):

Currently easiest way to test api routes protected with passport

```
Passport::actingAs(
    factory(User::class)->create(),
    ['create-servers']
);
```

[Passport testing on Laravel docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/passport#testing)

Comment: It seems to me that you are trying to test a route that uses web middleware instead of api.